# Is it normal for a brand new airflow installation to take multiple seconds to run a simple DAG?

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

I recently deployed airflow to a k8s cluster using the community [airflow helm chart](https://github.com/airflow-helm).

Everything is running fine and I can already run some dummy DAGs, etc. I'm mostly using the default values that come up with the community chart.

However, I've noticed that even a simple DAG takes many seconds to execute, tasks take always 1-2s in the queuing step for instance.

Here is the gantt chart for a simple DAG I created based on some examples online, as you can see, it takes over 1s to queue each task and the task themselves take seconds to execute too (even though they only involve 1-2 lines of python):

[gantt chart of dummy DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oksoN.png)

The code of this DAG is as follows:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator, PythonOperator


def _choosing_best_model(ti):
    accuracies = ti.xcom_pull(
        task_ids=["training_model_A", "training_model_B", "training_model_C"]
    )

    if max(accuracies) > 8:
        return "accurate"

    return "inaccurate"


def _training_model():
    # return an integer between 1 - 10
    return randint(1, 10)


with DAG(
    "dummy_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    training_model_tasks = [
        PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"training_model_{model_id}",
            python_callable=_training_model,
            op_kwargs={"model": model_id},
        )
        for model_id in ["A", "B", "C"]
    ]

    choosing_best_model = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id="choosing_best_model", python_callable=_choosing_best_model
    )

    accurate = BashOperator(task_id="accurate", bash_command="echo 'accurate'")

    inaccurate = BashOperator(task_id="inaccurate", bash_command=" echo 'inaccurate'")

    training_model_tasks >> choosing_best_model >> [accurate, inaccurate]
```

I know that airflow isn't meant to be extremely quick but I was surprised to see this when there is literally no load in the system yet.

Is this normal? If not, could you give me some pointers into what I can look into in order to troubleshoot this?

Comment: If you are running KubernetesExecutor then even a small task can take over 1 sec time because it starts a new pod to run each airflow task. for other executors it should be quick if the task is small

Comment: indeed, as @PankajSingh said, a KubernetesExecutor has to spin up a pod for every task you run in this dag, therefore, the task duration and dag duration are two different things. once the task turns green, it will almost always take milliseconds compared to the spinning of a pod

Comment: I'm using the Celery executor, which is the default in the helm chart, so I don't think that's the issue. I can also see that, by default, it spins up 2 celery worker pods and they stay up an running. I had a look at the worker pods' logs and I can't see anything strange, other than it takes over 3 seconds to run a tiny python task. I'm baffled really.

Comment: You can take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47450855) but in my company we already tried to speed Airflow up to no avail. I suppose it's because there's quite a lot of steps involved in between tasks. If you measure the time that your code is actually running (just the times at which your `_training_model` function actually starts and actually ends) and you'll see that it's blazing fast. Is the scheduling what takes its sweet time. And I must say: I _feel_ (just a feeling!!) it has improved in newer airflows compared to the 1.x versions, so imagine how it was!! 